# AsynFileUpload UploadedComplete function can't enable a Button control

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Master page form tag:**

```
    <form runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

---

**FileUpload.aspx**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlFileUpload">     
  <ContentTemplate> 
  <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" 
        style="margin-left: 0px" Width="350px" onclick="Save_Click" />
    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload
        ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

**FileUpload.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           btnSave.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

---

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Enabled = true;
    }
```

---

If i upload a file, UploadedComplete is infact fired ( I tested it by saving the file in a temp location ), but the "save" button is not getting enabled. Even the breakpoint able to hit the line:

```
btnSave.Enabled = true;
```

What is wrong with this code?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a little tweak.

Here is what you need to do make the button disable:

In you `<head>` tag:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function ClientUploadComplete(sender, e) {
            var btnSave = document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID %>");
            btnSave.disabled = true;
            btnSave.value = "Save";
        }
</script>
```

In your `<body>` tag:

Add `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` first and then:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlFileUpload">     
  <ContentTemplate> 
   <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID = "AsyncFileUpload1" runat = "server" OnClientUploadStarted = "" OnClientUploadComplete = "ClientUploadComplete" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```